# How to convert full C# project to vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

How to convert full C# project  to vb.net ?

Comment: Seriously... The reason so many converters exist is because the languages are practically find-and-replace compatible. I used to concede that there were certain tasks VB.NET was still good for but the truth is with C# 4 there's no reason to continue with VB.

Comment: I concede there were certain tasks better-suited to C# 3.x but with Visual Basic 10 there's no reason to continue with C#.

Comment: This is old now, but as an example I'm releasing sample code with an application and need to provide a VB .NET version of my C# projects

Comment: Ok, @Josh, using your logic, since Spanish is spoken in so many countries and so prevalent now even in the US, and since there are so many similarities as both Spanish and English have common roots, there's no reason to continue with English.

VB is much older than CS, and many of us are fluent in VB.  I can read CS, but it's like reading Spanish.  I can't write in CS, nor can I speak Spanish.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25114624/1369235). There is [a separate extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.CodeConverter) now to convert VB to C# and vice versa.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check out [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/), (specifically [V4.4](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/#SharpDevelop4x), which is the last version where this was supported). It has the feature you are asking for and its free.

Just go to Project > Convert

[image: Project > Convert Screenshot]

Comment: Good tool! I always used this online one. http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: The best part about Sharpdevelop is it converts the whole project (source files) from VB and C# and the other way.

Comment: And it's important that the new version sharp developer 5 is not containing convert option as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25114624/2721611). Use [version 4.4 of sharp develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/#SharpDevelop4x) for converting projects.

Comment: What feature do you use to do this? I just downloaded it and can't see any 'convert c# to vb.net functions.

Answer (score 5):

This is free: http://converter.telerik.com/ and it used to support multiple files by zip, but apparently doesn't anymore.

Comment: That doesn't convert an entire project - it only converts vb/cs files to each other. It doesn't appear, for instance, to touch your sln or vbproj/csproj files.

Comment: Also, interestingly from their [about page](http://converter.telerik.com/about.aspx), the heavy lifting for the  conversions is provided by **NRefactory**, which is maintained by the developers at **SharpDevelop**.

Comment: Also their page doesn't seem to have that "multiple files by zip" feature. Unless you have to pay for this feature?

Comment: @Pap is correct.  It does not support multiple files.