# How to use dll for VB.net to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net-2010

I have `dll` and sample code using `VB.net.`
However I need to use functions in `E5KDAQ.vb` using the `E5KDAQ.dll` file on C#. May I know how to achieve that?

Can anyone give any good examples on how to use it?

**E5KDAQ.vb**

```
 Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Environment
Module E5KDAQ

  'Public Cm As New MODULE_IOCHANNELS
  'TCP/IP Port Declaration
  Const TCP_MODBUS_PORT = 502                    'MODBUS/TCP
  Public Const UDP_ASC_PORT = 1025               'UDP ASCII Command
  Public Const UDP_ALARM_PORT = 5168             'UDP alarm port
  Public Const UDP_STREAM_PORT = 5148            'UDP stream port
  Public Const BROADCAST_IP = "255.255.255.255"


  '########## E5KDAQ.DLL Export Functions ###############################################//

  <DllImport("E5KDAQ.dll")> _
  Public Function E5K_GetRunTimeOS() As Integer
  End Function

  '----Open/Close module functions -----

  <DllImport("E5KDAQ.dll")> _
  Public Function E5K_OpenModuleUSB(ByVal devid As Integer) As Short
  End Function

  <DllImport("E5KDAQ.dll")> _
  Public Function E5K_GetLocalIP(ByRef ip0 As Byte,<[In](),Out()>Byref ip1 As Byte,<[In](),Out()> ByRef ip2 As Byte,<[In](),Out()>ByRef ip3 As Byte) As Short
  End Function
  <DllImport("E5KDAQ.dll")> _
  Public Function E5K_DebugPrint(ByVal str As String)
  End Function

End Module
```

I tried to Reference the dll file directly in my C# project but cannot with the following error:

[image]

I also tried to compile the VB project as class library 
with the following:

Class1.vb

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Environment
Public Class Class1
    'Public Cm As New MODULE_IOCHANNELS
    'TCP/IP Port Declaration
    Const TCP_MODBUS_PORT = 502                    'MODBUS/TCP
    Public Const UDP_ASC_PORT = 1025               'UDP ASCII Command
    Public Const UDP_ALARM_PORT = 5168             'UDP alarm port
    Public Const UDP_STREAM_PORT = 5148            'UDP stream port
    Public Const BROADCAST_IP = "255.255.255.255"
    'Type of Event
    Public Const ALARM_EVENT_TYPE = 0
    Public Const STREAM_EVENT_TYPE = 1

    Public Const HIGH_ALARM_EVENT = 0
    Public Const LOW_ALARM_EVENT = 1

    Public Const AD_ALARM_EVENT = 1
    Public Const DI_ALARM_EVENT = 0

  <DllImport("Kernel32.Dll")>
    Public Function CloseHandle(ByRef hObject As Integer) As Long
    End Function

    <DllImport("Kernel32.Dll")>
    Public Function CreateMutex(ByVal Attr As Integer, ByVal bInitial As Integer, ByVal lpName As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("Kernel32.Dll")>
    Public Function ReleaseMutex(ByVal hdnl As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    Public Function GetVarPtr(ByVal e As Object) As Integer
        Dim GC As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(e, GCHandleType.Pinned)
        Dim GC2 As Integer = GC.AddrOfPinnedObject.ToInt32
        GC.Free()
        Return GC2
    End Function

    '########## E5KDAQ.DLL Export Functions ###############################################//

    <DllImport("E5KDAQ.dll")>
    Public Function E5K_GetRunTimeOS() As Integer
    End Function

    '----Open/Close module functions -----

    <DllImport("E5KDAQ.dll")>
    Public Function E5K_OpenModuleUSB(ByVal devid As Integer) As Short
    End Function

    <DllImport("E5KDAQ.dll")>
    Public Function E5K_OpenModuleIP(ByVal IP As String, ByVal ConnectTimeout As Integer, ByVal TxTimeout As Integer, ByVal rxTimeout As Integer) As Short
    End Function
End Class
```

I got the following error:

[image]

So how do i import the E5KDAQ.dll so that i can compile it successfully as a class library for C# to use?

If anyone willing to help,i can send you the example vb project file since it is accessible to the public.

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: The point of programming in any .NET-compatible language is that no matter *which* you can reference the compiled assembly from *every* other assembly also produced by .NET. Thus you can reference an assembly which was written using C# in one written on VB.NET and vice versa. Just add a reference to your project/assembly.

Comment: Re the new error: it needs to be non-instance, then; in C# that is called `static` - in VB it is called `Shared`. So: mark those methods as `Shared`

Answer (score 2):

Resolved.
To include the dll dynamic linked library in your class library file,you have to use ***Shared*** Functione.g

Public Shared Function COMM_Close(ByVal ComPortNumber As Short) As Short
End Function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc31529

Also find another solution trying this out too.
Converting entire vb.net to csharp visual studio extensions

[How Convert VB Project to C# Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112982/how-convert-vb-project-to-c-sharp-project)

Error when running the class library on c#.
In the c# project i can see all the function,however when i build the project ,i got the following error:

[image]

[image]

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using E5KDAQCSHARP32;

namespace TestE5KDA
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int dival=0;
            int[] counterval = new int[23];
            // Test test1= new Test();
            Class1.E5K_ReadDIStatus(Module1.mid, ref dival);

            //read DI counter value
            Class1.E5K_ReadMultiDICounter(Module1.mid, 0, 2, counterval);
    for (int  i = 0; i<= Module1.mDIChannels -1; i++)
            {
                //Module1. mDICounterlist(i).Text = counterval(i);
                //Console.WriteLine(i);
                MessageBox.Show(counterval[i].ToString());
            }




        }

    }
}
```

Also put the dlls in the debug folder where the executable files are created,still getting the same error:

[image]
Any idea what is this?

Comment: Another issue occurs.When i tried applying it in c#,i got an error it cannot load DLL E5KDAQ.dll.I thought this dll is included in the vb itself when compiled into a class library?Added on my Answer

Comment: "I thought this dll is included in the vb itself" - nope, these are external imports - you still need the actual dll to be shipped. It needs to end up in the *execution* location, usually `bin/debug` or `bin/release` for testing. Usually you'd include the dll in the project and tell the build system to copy it to the output location.

Comment: I have already included the dll in the output debug  directory but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

2-and-a-bit options:

1. (simplest and probably preferred) compile your existing VB wrapper as a dll, and simply reference that dll from your C# project - and just use `var i = E5KDAQ.E5K_GetRunTimeOS();` etc from your C#
2. translate (manually or via a tool) the VB to C#; if all the VB does is advertise P/Invoke targets, this *probably* isn't very tricky
3. (the "and a bit") compile your existing VB wrapper as a dll, then use a tool like "reflector" to rewrite the compiled IL as C#

Comment: May you explain what do you mean by VB wrapper?Do you mean the E5KDAQ.vb file?Do you mean i create a VB project containing the E5KDAQ.vb and E5KDAQ.dll and compile it.Sorry i am new to vb.net and c#

Comment: @ThomasKoh the basic deployment unit for .NET assemblies is the dll; when you compile a VB or C# project, the output is *usually* a dll (unless you've told it to create an executable). That dll can be referenced by *other* projects. Note: if they're in the same Visual Studio solution, even this is overkill - you can add a "project reference" from your C# project to your VB project, and it'll manage the details (dlls, nupkgs, etc) automatically. You cannot uss a VB file inside a C# project, but you can have a VB project and a C# project in the same solution, and communicate between them.

Comment: I tried to add a reference to the dll file straight in my C# project but got the following error.Have updated it on my question.